# How to Reading and Plotting Notepad Data in GUI Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have 3 column notepad data and I want to plot it, I already finish the reading but it doesnt work when I plot them. Maybe the mistake is about to read it as column but I dont know how to do it this is the notepad data :

```
x           y           z
4335554.03  9142298.37  161.09
4335556.17  9142302.03  156.82
4335556.67  9142315.09  154.00
4335560.58  9142316.57  154.69
4335568.68  9142308.81  154.12
4335573.75  9142306.00  154.60
4335597.23  9142291.80  155.23
4335585.35  9142293.23  153.69
4335563.85  9142262.00  164.81
4335527.84  9142303.28  162.81
4335552.00  9142322.25  151.90
4335556.60  9142324.86  152.46
4335567.70  9142325.68  153.60
4335573.84  9142344.56  153.70
4335580.60  9142345.14  155.92
```

and this is my GUI Script :

```
% --- Executes on button press in Load.
function Load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Load (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global data
[filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'File Selector');
fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename),'r'); % read-only permission
handles.fileData = fscanf(fileID,'%d');
guidata(hObject, handles);
fullpathname = strcat(pathname, filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname);
set(handles.text1,'string',fullpathname)
set(handles.text2,'string',text)



% --- Executes on button press in Start.
function Start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Start (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global data
x = handles.fileData(:,1)
y = handles.fileData(:,2)
z = handles.fileData(:,3)
contour (x,y,z)
axes(handles.panel);
```

I cant figure it out, it always error at `y = handles.fileData(:,2)`

Comment: What is the error? Check the size of `handles.fileData`. I'm going to guess that it's a column vector and therefore doesn't have a second column. You'll want to reshape it: `handles.fileData = reshape(fscanf(fid, '%d'), 3, []).'`

Comment: do you mean I need to reshape the data ? what does the number 3 and [] for ?

Comment: `fscanf` is just going to read in a bunch of numbers and it doesn't care how many columns it is, but you want to reshape it so it's an N x 3 matrix, that's what the 3 is